# c++ limit cpu time to process

Tags: c++, c

I have this code:

```
pid_t vPid=fork(); 
    int vStat;   
    switch(vPid){
    case -1: perror("fork");
      exit(1);
    case 0:
      //proces fiu
      if(chdir("/var/code/p1")==0){
      system("make clean");
      system("make");   
          //limit on data
          struct rlimit vLimD;
          vLimD.rlim_cur = 10000000;//10Mb 
          vLimD.rlim_max =  10000000; //10Mb
      setrlimit(RLIMIT_DATA, &vLimD);
          //limit on cpu time
          struct rlimit vLimCPU;
          vLimCPU.rlim_cur = 10;//10 sec
          vLimCPU.rlim_max = 10;//10 sec
          cout<<"limits return "<<setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU, &vLimCPU);
  execl("/var/code/p1/p1","",NULL);
      }
      else {exit(1);}
      break;
    default: 
       while(wait(&vStat)!=vPid);
          break;
    }
```

The process /var/code/p1/p1 runs for 40 seconds, and I want to limit this process to run for just 10 seconds with `vLimitCPU(setrlimit)`, and after 10 sec do something, but is not print nothing like "limits return value" (the first `setrlimit` returns 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The man page `setrlimit(2)` states:

> CPU time limit in seconds.  When the process  reaches  the  soft
>                 limit, it is sent a SIGXCPU signal.  The default action for this
>                 signal is to terminate the process.  However, the signal can  be
>                 caught,  and the handler can return control to the main program.

Probably you do not receive any output because your output stream is **not flushed** (output `std::endl` to solve this problem). The program may be killed by the signal before it can flush its output buffers. It may also well be that the buffers don't survive `execl()` in the first place.

Some more advice:

- Then you should implement said signal handler and your program will
  continue from there. Implement it to see whether the signal is
  caught.
- Note that you will also need a fallback solution for the case that
  the process unexpectedly terminates before CPU time is up.
- Note also that if I take it correctly, you also need to account for
  the CPU time already used by your process when setting the limit.